# How to Select first chip as default progrmatically in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, material-components-android, android-chips

I have defined my chipgroup in my XML and adding chips programtically as below:

```
chip_group_filter.removeAllViews();
        for(FilterModel filterModel : Common.categorySelected.getFilters()){
            Chip chip = (Chip) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_filter_item, null);
            chip.setText(new StringBuilder(filterModel.getName()));
            chip.setCheckedIconVisible(false);
            chip_group_filter.addView(chip);
            chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.lightGray);
            chip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            chip.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        seeSelectedChip(chip);
                        serviceListViewModel.loadServicesByFilter(chip.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
```

I want to select first chip as default chip and want to execute checkChangedListener event for the same. How to write that logic?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the the method: [`chipGroup.check(id)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup#check). It works with the `id` of the chip to select.

You can use:

```
chipGroup.check(chip.getId());
```

or if you don't have the id

```
chipGroup.check(chipGroup.getChildAt(0).getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this by this code in XML

```
  <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:checked="true"
        android:id="@+id/chip_song"
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

```
 val firstChipId = chipGroup.getChildAt(0)?.id ?: View.NO_ID      
    chipGroup.check(firstChipId)
```